# wpdb update method is updating but not refreshing the current page data

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have used wpdb->update method to update the data and it is working correctly as it is updating the data in the database but the issue is the data is not refreshing on submitting the form . 
action of the form is empty and method is post

Comment: Can we see your code? But make sure that you update the data before you actually display/retrieve the data.

Comment: yes that was the issue i was updating the database at the end . now i have updated the data before retrieving it and now it is working fine . thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to redirect the url to the previous page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/340759/i-want-to-redirect-the-url-to-the-previous-page)

Comment: how it is duplicate sir ? this is update method and other question is delete method .... please read the questions sir and then reply . thanks