# I want to redirect the url to the previous page

Tags: redirect, wp-list-table

I have created a table in which i have delete link something like 
http://localhost/wptheme/wp-admin/admin.php?page=batch-op-settings&action=batch-delete&post_id=5
and i have added a code to delete the post

```
if ($action == 'batch-delete') {
    require_once (plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'views/single_batch_delete.php');
  }
```

code in the required file is

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) == 'batch-delete') {
    global $wpdb;
    $delete_batch = $wpdb->delete( 'batch_number', array(
        'id'=>$_GET['post_id']
    ) );
    wp_redirect( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page="batch-op-settings"', 302, 'Deleted' );
}
```

the data row is deleted but it is not redirecting to the all batches code all data i have used wp_redirect function i have also used header() function but it shows this error

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

I want to know is there any better way to handle this issue or any solution with the current code .

Comment: Are you running the code (which deletes the data row and do the redirect) within any hook?

Comment: no there is no hook ...

Comment: I'd suggest you using hooks like `admin_action_batch-delete` to handle your plugin action. From [hooks like that](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-admin/admin.php/), performing redirects shouldn't give you the "headers already sent" issue.

Comment: I am confused in how to use action as you preferred

Comment: It's similar to how you use any other hooks like `admin_menu` - `add_action( 'admin_action_batch-delete', function(){ // update/delete your data and then redirect } )`. [Example](https://gist.github.com/5ally/c4892a9ce9bf20799fd3040f8c7af080)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in functions.php and check it works or not.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'app_output_buffer');
function app_output_buffer() {
        ob_start();
}
```

let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: awesome ... but i dont understand the logic behind it ...

Comment: data are printing while theme is rendering output to the browser. meanwhile we redirect to other page using  wp_redirect() take away from that page before the whole page is renders to the browser. This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer. you can see more about ob_start() at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: okY great thankyou :) one more thing if you can answer ... in the redirection thing i want to print the message after redirecting how can i do that ?

Comment: you need to pass query_string variable with info about deleted item then you can use $_GET['']  to get that and dislpay message using add_action( 'admin_notices',  'admin_notices_callback'  ); function.

Comment: I have used sessions for the work but i will surely look into your way . thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely your condition:

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) == 'batch-delete') {
```

`isset()` returns `true` or `false`, not the value of the parameter. If you want to also check the value you need to check it like this:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && 'batch-delete' === $_GET['action'] ) {
```

Then make sure you use `exit;` after running `wp_redirect()`. From [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/):

> Note: [wp_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) does not exit automatically, and should
>   almost always be followed by a call to `exit;`:
>
> ```
> wp_redirect( $url );
> exit;
> ```
>
> Exiting can also be selectively manipulated by using
>   [wp_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) as a conditional in conjunction with the
>   ‘[wp_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_redirect/)’ and ‘[wp_redirect_location](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_redirect_location/)’ filters:
>
> ```
> if ( wp_redirect( $url ) ) {
>     exit;
> }
> ```

Lastly, for the redirect URL, you'd be better off using the `admin_url()` function. Plus, the `page` query string shouldn't be in quotes.

```
wp_redirect( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=batch-op-settings' ), 302, 'Deleted' );
```

Comment: I have tried exit; but it is not solving the issue

Comment: I've updated my answer with 2 other issues

Comment: no luck i have tried both of your updated edits .